# Suggestion to roll back credit card transaction on PHP

Tags: php

I would like a suggestion for a e-commerce solution that I am currently developing. 
The web app is developed in PHP, database is MYSQL and the Credit Card company is CIELO (old Visanet) and everything is all set. My company is a gateway payment, where I receive from my clients through HTTP post the following fields:

```
- order_id; 
- value; 
- credit_card
- exp_date
_ ccd_field
```

I process all the information with the credit card company and after this process, I return a $_POST to my client with the order_id, value and status (OK, rejected or try again). 
My question is: 
What if the return fails for any reason, after the credit card is captured, what can I do in order to check the $_POST and rollback the XML file that I've sent to CIELO. 
Thanks for helping me out! 
Regards, 
Thiago Casteliano. 
São Paulo/Brazil.

Comment: Are you asking 'How to cancel the transaction with Cielo?' If so, the answer will depend on their requirements. I don't see how we can answer you when you've posted no code, nor any details of how the transation is processed by Cielo.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what data you're receiving from your customers, but if full credit card numbers are involved, you are going to need to pay a lot more attention to security than you seem to be doing right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the process into:

1. add transaction,
2. execute added transaction, and you can add another call:
3. check transaction state.

By doing that you are sure, that the client is able to recheck the transaction, and that he can resend it. If there is some other problem, the transaction will just wait for being executed.

If you are using HTTP, you won't be otherwise able to check if the caller received the status (unless you will require some confirmation, or if you are the caller in the second phase).

The above nicely fits into RESTful approach:

1. POST to /transactions with transaction details,
2. POST to /transactions/{transaction_id}/execute in order to execute transaction,
3. GET to /transactions/{transaction_id} in order to see transaction data (namely the status of it, as I would not show the credit card number here),